# REST API call Cross-Domain to My Site Personal Site Quick Launch Links

Tags: 2013, quick-launch, mysite, rest

Hoping someone can help me with a concept I am trying to accomplish.

**Scenario**

Basically I need to replicate (on a Publishing Portal) the Add/Edit Links in the left navigation of My Site Host (My Site Host and Publishing Portal are on different domains).

These links come from the Quick Launch List in a users personal site:

```
http://mysitehost/personal/userId/_layouts/15/quiklnch.aspx
```

I also have the REST endpoint to retrieve these Quick Launch Links and can successfully pass this into browser and see the xml output returned of the Quick Launch List:

```
http://mysitehost/personal/userId/_api/Web/Navigation/QuickLaunch
```

**Possible Solutions**

- I have tried using JQuery $.ajax GET method to query the above url but obviously returns an error because access denied because the request is coming from a different domain
  Went down the SharePoint 2013 App direction and installed on the Publishing Site and tried to change client context to mysitehost to read the quick launch list but still didn't work (obviously assuming because its trusted and installed on the publishing site not the mysitehost)
- Create a Proxy Page to read contents of the Quick Launch list page (like www.sharepointjohn.com/sharepoint-2010-cross-domain-proxy-page-for-client-side-scripts/) but I need to also be able to update/edit the links from the Publishing Portal as well not just read

I am trying to figure out what I am missing to find a solution for this? It is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is.
You will need a workaround for cross-domain calls ([here I gathered some](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/129194/cross-domain-calls-in-sharepoint-comparism)) so you can access the list-data. I would recommend a CSOM web-service.

Afterwards you can modify the current quick-launch.