# Cross-Domain Calls in SharePoint - Comparism

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, rest, cross-domain

### Basic Example

- *mysite.mysharepoint.com* has clientside code that wants to access a list on *mysharepoint.com* due to whatever reason.
- the [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) forbids this

---

### Possible Workarounds

**SSOM**

While this is easily possible, I tend to avoid serverside code.

*Con*

- SSOM

**Edit web.config**

[An simple web.config edit allows the communication.](http://blog.karstein-consulting.com/2014/03/18/cross-site-scripting-with-sharepoint-2013-rest-calls/)

*Con*

- all front-end servers have to be modified
- hardware changes can affect the outcome

**App**

For Apps SharePoint provides some ways to enable cross-domain calls. ([`SP.RequestExecutor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn735924(v=office.15).aspx), [`SP.WebProxy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj850796(v=office.15).aspx)) so you could communicate with the app and the app communicates cross domain. Same for CSOM apps while you here can work without the policy.

*Con*

- need of an app

**WebService**

Editing your own web-service's web.config isn't as critical as editing the SharePoint one. The web-service itself could access the data via SSOM (needs to be hosted on a SP server) or CSOM (much more the 2013 way). If configured correct, the service returns [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) which can be consumed.

*Con*

- need of an web-service

---

### Conclusion

If you have any suggestions or know other ways to solve the problem ([SP365 Custom Action?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163954(v=office.15).aspx)) feel free to add them to this collection.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure that YQL would solve it. As below sample

```
var site = url; //Cross Domain URL goes here
var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from xml where url="' + site + '"') + '&format=xml&callback=?';
// Request that YSQL string, and run a callback function.
// Pass a defined function to prevent cache-busting.
$.getJSON(yql, function(data){
   console.log(data.results[0]);
});
```

or

can try with Ajax as below,

```
$.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    cache : true,
    type : "get",
    data : _data to be sent,
    global : false,
    dataType : "jsonp", //Specifying JSONP would make the magic for cross domain call
    jsonp : false,
    success : function jsonpCallback (response) {
        console.log(response);
   alert(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with my example